# How can i securely acces my website from the notebook ? (just re-installed windows7)

Tags: windows, ssl

I have an website, which has an active SSL Certificate.
When me or somebody else enter on my website, iit says that is secure. 
First it was unsecure until i bought a ssl license, and provider installed it for me. 
I use a .htacces to redirect all requests to https:// .
When i use all of my devices from house (phone, two notebooks) it says that is secure website.
Friends told me also, when they enter the website from their houses. 
Well.. i just re-installed windows 7 on one of my notebooks, and now when i acces my website from that notebook it says is Insecure. When i try from my phone or the other notebook it says secure.

How can i solve it ?

Comment: Your notebook should say *why* it's insecure.

Comment: It says Invalid Ssl script. But say it for 100% that my page has an 100% valid ssl script.
The other notebook says that is valid, my phone says is valid, other friends phones or notebooks says it is valid.....

Comment: Give us the actual, exact message it's giving you. I don't know of any browser that calls a SSL certificate a "script".

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved, i just installed all windows updates and everything is right :)
Thank you ceejayoz and to everybody else.